# Internet of Money git download error

Tags: money, learning, make

I tried to download the pdf from the following repository but i get an error

https://github.com/merklebloom/IoMv1
Ive done the following:
$  git clone https://github.com/merklebloom/IoMv1.git
$  cd IoMv1/
$  make pdf

It fails to create the pdf.

And I get this error message:

> if [ ! -d "_build" ]; then \  mkdir _build; \     cp -R -L
>   /etc/asciidoc/images _build; \    cp images/* _build; \   cp
>   chapters/en/* _build; \   cp conf/* _build; \ fi; \
>
> export
>   XML_CATALOG_FILES=/usr/share/xml/docbook/schema/dtd/catalog.xml; \ cd
>   _build; \ a2x --format=pdf --conf-file=a2x.conf --fop --xsl-file=custom-docbook-styles.xsl -k --verbose master.asciidoc; \
>
> /bin/sh: 3: a2x: not found Makefile:65: recipe for target 'create_pdf'
>   failed make: *** [create_pdf] Error 127

Same goes for creating any other file such as pdf, html, epub, kindle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a problem with git.  The problem is that the program 'a2x' is not found.  Either you don't have it installed, or it can't be found in your path.